# Django rest framework get one to many relationship data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a django model named `Event`, which references `Customer` model.

```
event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
customer = models.ForeignKey(customer_models.Customer, db_index=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='customer_events', null=True)
event_location = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
event_date = models.DateField()
```

I need to get the customer list along with the latest event name for each user in the API.

Customer serializers.py file is

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Customer views.py file is

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Customer` model you can have a `property` that returns the latest event name for a Customer instance:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def latest_event_name(self):
        """Return latest event name."""

        # self.customer_events.order_by('event_date').last()
        latest_event = self.customer_events.order_by('-event_date').first()

        return latest_event.event_name if latest_event else None
```

In your serializer you can then add a `ReadOnlyField` for `latest_event_name`:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    latest_event_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```